# Calling a function in flash object only works internally

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop

I'm using a package to play back .wav files in Flash. I can make wav's play back, however, what I cannot do is trigger their playback from a button. I suspect this is because I've misunderstood the this keyword. Below is an example.

You can see that when I call  playBackTest() directly it works; when I call this object from a button it doesn't.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

```
package  
 {  
    import flash.display.Sprite;  
    import flash.net.URLLoader;  
    import flash.net.URLRequest;  
    import flash.events.Event;  
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;  
    import org.as3wavsound.WavSound;  
    import org.as3wavsound.WavSoundChannel;
    import org.as3wavsound.WavSoundPlayer;
    import flash.display.*; 
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;

     public final class PlaySound extends MovieClip  
     {  
        var tts:WavSound;
        var soundUrl:String;
        var soundType:String;
        var statusTextField:TextField  = new TextField();
        var WavChannel:WavSoundChannel; 
        var statusMC:MovieClip;
        var totalRemainingLoad:int = 0;

        public function PlaySound(soundUrl:String, repeats:String, volumeLevel:Number, statusMC):void {  

            //set variables of this object when it's initiated 
            this.soundUrl = soundUrl;
            this.statusMC = statusMC;
            loadWav();      
        }

        public function loadWav() { 
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(soundUrl); 
            var wav:URLLoader = new URLLoader();  
            wav.dataFormat = 'binary';  
            wav.load(urlRequest);
            wav.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
            this.statusMC.addChild(statusTextField);            
            wav.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, makeWav);  
        }

        private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
            var loadTime:Number = event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal;
            var LoadPercent:uint = Math.round(100 * loadTime);
            statusTextField.text =  LoadPercent + ' % loaded ';
        }       

        public function makeWav(e:Event) {  
            this.tts = new WavSound(e.target.data as ByteArray);
            playBackTest();
        }

        public function playBackTest() {
            trace('This makes audio play'); 
            this.tts.play(); 
        }       

        public function playBack() {
            trace('This does not if called from outside with a button press'); 
            this.tts.play(); 
        }   


    }  
}
```

Comment: Where is Button Clip(Sprite or MovieClip)?
Are You add a MouseEvent? btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick); or btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);

Comment: FML, so if the button is made inside the package in question then it works just like you'd expect. However, the way this works at the moment is that it dynamically instantiates the above class lots of times


var MySound:PlaySound = new PlaySound(sound_file_location, loop, volumeLevel, statusMC);
        
     sounds[bank_index][bank_option_index] = MySound;

and then the package that makes these objects can't call the playBack() function - and make it play. Although it does trace the text in that function. Any ideas?

Comment: FML, so if the button is made inside the package in question then it works just like you'd expect. However, the way this works at the moment is that it dynamically instantiates the above class lots of times, like this 

`var MySound:PlaySound = new PlaySound(sound_file_location, loop, volumeLevel, statusMC); sounds[bank_index][bank_option_index] = MySound;` 

and then the package that makes these objects can't call the playBack() function - and make it play. Although it does trace the text in that function. Any ideas? – Jim 13 mins ago

Comment: If it traces the text but doesn't play the sound, my first guess would be the sound isn't completely loaded or ready for playback at that point. It might also help if you post a bit of your code for when these are being created and when playBack() is being called.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function PlaySound():void 
{  
     if(stage) init();
     else      addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);    
}

private function init(e:Event=null):void
{
     removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
     loadWav();
}
```

---

Your Class is inheritance MovieClip, so PlaySoundClass should be a added Stage.
If your class not perfectly addedToStage. not available Class.

your internal var change To Public var or getter/setter Method. because must be accessed out to in.

and access your class following codes.

```
var mySound:PlaySound = new PlaySound(); 
mySound.soundUrl = "your URL"; 
mySound.repeats = "your Repeats"; 
mySound.volumeLevel = volumeLevel; 
mySound.statusMc= your MovieClip;
```

Comment: I hate Flash. I love you. I'll give it a go now.

Comment: OK, doesn't seem to work. To be honest I'm not sure what the explanation means, but now it doesn't even call the PlaySound method when I make a new PlaySound object. I should perhaps say that I have many sound objects and I'm loading them into an array.